# Visual Studio 2015 extention to treat string HTML in JavaScript file like HTML editing

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, visual-studio, knockout.js

When working with my knockout components it would be nice if the HTML in my template would act like editing HTML in an .html file. For example, in the sample below, the template is a string, but I would like it to have the syntax styling and other IDE sugar as if I'm editing HTML in an html or aspx file. I'm sure this same thing would be helpful for Angular 2 components. Is there an extension that gives me this functionality?

```
ko.components.register('like-widget', {
    viewModel: function (params) {
        // Data: value is either null, 'like', or 'dislike'
        this.chosenValue = params.value;

        // Behaviors
        this.like = function () { this.chosenValue('like'); }.bind(this);
        this.dislike = function () { this.chosenValue('dislike'); }.bind(this);
    },
    template:
        '<div class="like-or-dislike" data-bind="visible: !chosenValue()">\
            <button data-bind="click: like">Like it</button>\
            <button data-bind="click: dislike">Dislike it</button>\
        </div>\
        <div class="result" data-bind="visible: chosenValue">\
            You <strong data-bind="text: chosenValue"></strong> it\
        </div>'
});
```

Comment: resharper i think does that.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an extension that I use to provide the HTML syntax highlighting in Javascript files:

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/7ad6f617-0903-4690-910e-5d555faf0038

You can also find it from within VS via the Extension Gallery.

Comment: Looks like it doesn't support VS2015.

Comment: Here's another syntax highlighter for JS that looks to support VS2015 - but it doesn't look like it's free: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3773ffb5-b656-4ddb-95a0-0cbc3a11d4fe

Comment: Yeah I just posted about that one. It looks good but it doesn't work with my sample code.

Answer (score 0):

I found [JsHighlight](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3773ffb5-b656-4ddb-95a0-0cbc3a11d4fe), but it looks like it doesn't work with the sample code I posted, with the multiline string.